# SSRS textbox expression

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to combine data in a tablix grouped by ItemName.

With a filter ItemName = "gender", getting the Name and ItemCount is trivial by grouping in ItemName.

But I need to show data for two types of ItemName, i,e., gender Female number next to GCgender Female number. I can alter the tablix filter to ItemType="gender" OR ItemType="CGgender", no problem.

Given a dataset structured as:

```
[ItemType]      [ItemName]                      [ItemCount]
---------------------------------------------------------
CGgender,   "Female",                           4547
gender,     "Female",                           53776
gender,     "Male",                             27303
CGgender,   "Male",                             1873
CGgender,   "Not Collected",                    53
gender,     "Not Collected",                    1248
gender,     "Transgender - Female to Male",     27
CGgender,   "Transgender - Female to Male",     2
CGgender,   "Transgender - Male to Female",     1
gender,     "Transgender - Male to Female",     33
```

And a report tablix required to look like:

```
[ItemName]    [gender ItemCount]  [CGgender ItemCount]
 Female     |      53776         |        4547
```

I guess my real question is how to explicitly get ItemCount for ItemType = "gender" and Itemname = "Female" in a tablix textbox next to ItemCount for ItemType = "CGgender" and Itemname = "Female". `=Fields!ItemCount` returns either gender or CGgender depending on how it feels and so does `=Lookup("CaregiverGender", Fields!ItemName.Value, Fields!ItemCount.Value, "AllCounts")`.

Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data:

[image]

You can do this with a standard Matrix:

[image]

This gives the results:

[image]

Couple of other notes... You would probably need to order the column group `ItemType` as `Z->A` and use an expression like `=Fields!ItemType.Value & " ItemCount"` to match your exact headings.

Comment: Now, another question! I added total column to the left of CGgender. So far, so good, it totals the two as it should. Now the client wants me to add a percent number to one of the gender textboxes that refers to the other one, e.g., =Sum(Fields!ItemCount.value) "gender value" / "CGgender value". I don't see how to reference a value for a matrix column textbox that hasn't been "created" yet. Any help is greatly appreciated!